# Фильтрация массива объектов в приложении Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

помогите, пожалуйста, с таким вопросом. Имеется в приложении массив с объектами, в котором хранится информация о блюдах. Необходимо реализовать несколько фильтров, которые должны работать одновременно, а именно: по категориям, по остроте блюд, и также есть группа из двух чекбоксов ('без орехов' и 'только вегетарианские'). Также есть кнопка добавления блюда в корзину. Через computed я фильтрую массив в соответствии со своими фильтрами. Но проблема в том, что когда массив отфильтрован по каким либо фильтрам, добавление в корзину идёт по индексу начального массива (без фильтров). Ниже привожу код кнопки добавления и одного из фильтров. Как это исправить?

```
addProduct(index) {
 this.cart.count +=1;
 this cart.price += this.products[index].price;
 this.productInCart.push({
  product: {
   price: this.products[index].price,
   name: this.products[index].name,
   image: this.products[index].image
  },
  count: 1
 })
}
```

```
computed: {
 filterProducts() {
 if (this.filters.category==='' && this.filters.nuts) {
   return this.products.filter(item => item.spiciness >= this.filters.speciesValue)
  }
  // и т.д. другие фильтры
 }
}
```

Comment: Добавляйте по идентификатору блюда

Comment: Михаил, а можно чуточку подробнее?)

Comment: В объектах продукта должно быть поле, по которому вы сможете идентифицировать данный продукт. Если его нет, то самое время создать его. При нажатии на кнопку - передавайте не индекс, а идентификатор. По данному идентификатору вы сможете найти нужный вам продукт из списка и добавить его в корзину

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!!